# How to calculate matrix multiplication in which matrix is saved as vector

Tags: julia

I have two symmetric matrices `A`, `B` and a vector `X`. The dimension of `A` is n by n, the dimension of `B` is n by n, the dimension of `X` is n by 1. Let the element at `i`th row and `j`th column of matrix `A` denoted by `A[i,j]`.

Since `A` is symmetric, only each column of the upper triangular matrix of `A` is saved. The matrix `A` is saved as an array：

```
Vector_A = [A[1,1],
            A[1,2], A[2,2],
            A[1,3], A[2,3], A[3,3],
            A[1,4], A[2,4], A[3,4], A[4,4],
            ...,
            A[1,n], A[2,n], ..., A[n,n]]
```

The matrix `B` is saved in the same format as matrix `A`. Now I would like to calculate `ABA` without transforming `Vector_A`, `Vector_B` back to matrix `A, B`. Since `ABA` is also symmetric, I would like to save the `ABA` in the same way as an array. How can I do it in Julia?

I would also like to calculate `X'AX` without transforming `Vector_A` back to matrix `A` where `X'` denotes `transpose(X)`. How can I do it in Julia?

Comment: Are you sure that you need to store the matrix efficiently? The regular memory layout of the full array might outweigh the performance benefit. But if you really need the memory saving, you would ideally write a new `EfficientSymmetric{T} <: AbstractArray{T,2}` struct, so that you can "use it like an array". Maybe this discussion is relevant? https://discourse.julialang.org/t/symmetric-matrices/4086

Comment: AFAIK, Julia has sparse matrix types. So instead of building up your own optimized layout, maybe all you need to do is use sparse matrices.

Comment: The last time I thought about this was when working on an algorithm Model Confidence Set in my [ForecastEval.jl](https://github.com/colintbowers/ForecastEval.jl) package. I implemented the algorithm two ways: 1) storing just the upper-triangular portion of matrices to save on memory, 2) storing the entire matrix, which uses twice as much memory but allows me to use BLAS routines. The second algorithm runs significantly faster. The first option may indeed be better for your problem, but it is worth at least investigating the second also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement your own data structures that inherit from the the `AbstractMatrix` type.

For example this could be done as:

```
struct SymmetricM{T} <: AbstractMatrix{T}
    data::Vector{T}
end
```

So we have a symmetric matrix that is using only a vector for its data storage.
Now you need to implement functions so it actually behaves like a matrix so you can let the Julia magic work.

We start by providing the size of our new matrix datatype.

```
function Base.size(m::SymmetricM) 
   n = ((8*length(m.data)+1)^0.5-1)/2
   nr = round(Int, n)
   @assert n ≈ nr "The vector length must match the number of triang matrix elements"
   (nr,nr)
end
```

In this code `nr` will be calculate every time to `checkbounds` is done on matrix. Perhaps in your production implementation you might want to move it to be a field of `SymmetricM`. You would scarify some elasticity and store 8 bytes more but would gain on the speed.

Now the next function we need is to calculate position of the vector on the base of matrix indices. Here is one possible implementation.

```
function getix(idx)::Int
    n = size(m)[1]
    row, col = idx
    #assume left/lower triangular
    if col > row
        row = col
        col = idx[1]
    end
    (row-1)*row/2 + col
end
```

Having that now we can implement `getindex` and `setindex` functions:

```
@inline function Base.getindex(m::SymmetricM, idx::Vararg{Int,2})
    @boundscheck checkbounds(m, idx...)
    m.data[getix(idx)]
end

@inline function Base.getindex(m::SymmetricM{T}, v::T, idx::Vararg{Int,2}) where T
    @boundscheck checkbounds(m, idx...)
    m.data[getix(idx)] = v
end
```

Now let us test this thing:

```
julia> m = SymmetricM(collect(1:10))
4×4 SymmetricM{Int64}:
 1  2  4   7
 2  3  5   8
 4  5  6   9
 7  8  9  10
```

You can see that we have provide elements of only one triangle (be it the lower or upper - they are the same) - and we got the full matrix!

This is indeed a fully valid Julia matrix so all matrix algebra should work on it:

```
julia> m * SymmetricM(collect(10:10:100))
4×4 Array{Int64,2}:
  700   840  1010  1290
  840  1020  1250  1630
 1010  1250  1580  2120
 1290  1630  2120  2940
```

Note that the result of multiplication is a Matrix rather than `SymmetricM` - to get a `SymmetricM` you need to overload the `*` operator to accept 2 `SymmetricM` arguments. For illustrative purposes let us show a custom operator overloading with the minus sign `-`:

```
import Base.-
-(m1::SymmetricM, m2::SymmetricM) = SymmetricM(m1.data .- m2.data)
```

And now you will see that substraction of `SymmetricM` is going to return another `SymmetricM`:

```
julia> m-m
4×4 SymmetricM{Int64}:
 0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0
```

In this way you can build a full triangular matrix algebra system in Julia.

Note that however the `getix` function has an `if` statement so access to `SymmetricM` elements without using the `data` field will be much slower than those of a regular matrix so perhaps you should try to overload as many operators as is required for your project.